# Python-Pymongo : InvalidDocument on key <bson.ObjectId>

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am currently trying to build a query in a string then after that use `eval` (`ast_eval`) to transform it to a `dict` in order to pass up to pymongo update.

```
for item in default_properties:
    query = '{"_id": {ObjectId:"%s"}}' % (oid)
if (doc["diff_id"] == diff_id):
                default_val_pos = [line[0], line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4],line[5],line[6],line[7],line[8]]
                update_val = '{ "$set":{"properties.%s": default_val_pos[%d] } }' % (item,idx)
                db.routes.update(eval(query), eval(update_val))
```

I thought that it should be okay now since in mongoshell itself accepts the same query, the only difference is that I used `from bson.objectid import ObjectId` to format it well, however, this error occured:

```
InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was <class 'bson.objectid.ObjectId'>
```

As far as I see it, I don't have any "field key" that is not a string other than the ObjectId and hmmm I don't think the I should turn ObjectId in a hardcoded string lol. So I was wondering if someone can explain what's the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should just be:

```
query = '{"_id": ObjectId("%s")}' % (oid)
```

You're getting confused with MongoDB Extended JSON, which you can evaluate like:

```
query = '{"_id": {"$oid": "%s"}}' % (oid)
from bson import json_util
query_dict = json_util.loads(query)
```

But the simplest way to build your query is with Python literals:

```
query_dict = {"_id": ObjectId(oid)}
```

Comment: ah! so that's it. Thank for the clear and concise explanation where I'm wrong. And also for suggesting the last one! I forgot that "I COULD" do that! thanks again!