# error : InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was .. Inserting pandas multiindex dataframe to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, dataframe, pymongo, multi-index

I have dataframe like this and trying to insert it into mongodb.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(2, 10).reshape(-1, 2),

    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
        ['data', 'data1'],
        ['F', 'K'],
    ])
)

   data data1
    F   K
0   2   3
1   4   5
2   6   7
3   8   9
```

when I try to add this to my collection in mongodb

```
collection.insert_many(df.to_dict('records'))
```

getting this error

> InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was ('data', 'F')

I really deep look into this but really cannot find any relevant posts, here are the some closer but those discuss key's with `integer` errors. My key's are already string but still getting the error.

[Why using integer as a key with pymongo doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592468/why-using-integer-as-a-key-with-pymongo-doesnt-work)

[Python-Pymongo : InvalidDocument on key <bson.ObjectId>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808484/python-pymongo-invaliddocument-on-key-bson-objectid)

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message, you are creating a multi-index on the key; pymongo only supports string indexes, not tuples, so you must refactor your dataframe so that the keys are strings.

I can't really tell what you are trying to achieve so can't offer much more than that.